# Why does Supabase's `onAuthStateChange` trigger just the once?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase

I recently started experimenting with Next.js and I read that Supabase is great with it for smaller projects. What I'm doing is a small e-commerce website where registered users can access a few protected routes with personalized data.

My problem happens when I try to create a client-side component  that renders different links based on user login status. From what I read in Supabase's docs the best way to implement this is to listen for auth events with `onAuthStateChange` within a `useEffect()` hook and update the UI when the user logs in or out. However, the event triggers only once on page load and says `INITIAL_SESSION`.

These are the login and logout functions I have:

```
"use server";

import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

import { createClient } from "@/utils/actions";

export async function login(formData: FormData) {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const supabase = createClient(cookieStore);

  const data = {
    email: formData.get("email") as string,
    password: formData.get("password") as string,
  };

  const { error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword(data);

  if (error) {
    redirect("/error");
  }

  revalidatePath("/", "layout");
  redirect("/");
}

export async function logout() {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const supabase = createClient(cookieStore);

  const { error } = await supabase.auth.signOut();

  if (error) {
    redirect("/error");
  }

  revalidatePath("/", "layout");
  redirect("/");
}
```

And this is the code inside my `useEffect()` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const { data } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
      console.log(event);
    });

    return () => {
      data.subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

Is there a way to fix it or am I fundamentally mistaken about implementing this type of functionality?

I tried different ways to call `.onAuthStateChange` but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing client and server supabase clients here. The server client is not connected to the client-side/browser client, meaning when you change the login status via a server action, that won't be reflected in the browser client. If you're doing server things, best to keep everything server rendered and not use the browser client for onauthstatechange.